# Doctrine listener - run action only if a field has changed

Tags: php, doctrine

How do I check if field has changed?

I'd like to trigger an action in `preSave()` only if specific field has changed, e.q.

```
public function preSave() {
    if ($bodyBefore != $bodyNow) {
         $this->html = $this->_htmlify($bodyNow);
    }
}
```

The question is how to get this `$bodyBefore` and `$bodyNow`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please don't fetch the database again! This works for Doctrine 1.2, I haven't tested lower versions.

```
// in your model class
public function preSave($event) {
  if (!$this->isModified())
    return;

  $modifiedFields = $this->getModified();
  if (array_key_exists('title', $modifiedFields)) {
    // your code
  }
}
```

Check out the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Record/1_2#method_getmodified), too.

Answer (score 2):

Travis's answer was almost right, because the problem is that the object is overwritten when you do the Doctrine query. So the solution is:

```
public function preSave($event)
{
  // Change the attribute to not overwrite the object
  $oDoctrineManager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance(); 
  $oDoctrineManager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_HYDRATE_OVERWRITE, false); 

  $newRecord = $event->getInvoker();
  $oldRecord = $this->getTable()->find($id);

  if ($oldRecord['title'] != $newRecord->title)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this out.

```
public function preSave($event)
{
   $id = $event->getInvoker()->id;
   $currentRecord = $this->getTable()->find($id);

   if ($currentRecord->body != $event->getInvoker()->body)
   {
      $event->getEnvoker()->body = $this->_htmlify($event->getEnvoker()->body);
   }   
}
```

Comment: When I add `$event` parameter to `preSave()` the method is not executed at all.

Comment: Which version of Doctrine are you using?