# Can you compare and update two stdClass arrays?

Tags: php, stdclass

I have two stdclass objects namely

```
stdClass Object
(
    [apple] => 10
    [orange] => 10
    [grape] => 10
    [banana] => 20
    [mango] => 30
)

stdClass Object
(
    [apple] => 15
)
```

Can I update apple like a normal array operation? Or is there another way to do so?

Also whats the difference between this and a normal array?

Comment: Those are objects, not arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [compare object properties and show diff in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911067/compare-object-properties-and-show-diff-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You would loop through them using a normal `foreach` loop:

```
$obj = new StdClass;

$obj->test = 1;
$obj->more_testing = 2;

foreach ($obj as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ': ' . $value . '\n\n';
}
```

or you could cast them as an your objects as an array using `(array)`.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/LB0g)

**Reading Material**

[Iterations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)

Answer (score 0):

See the official documentation on [comparing objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php):

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values (values are compared with ==), and are instances of the same class.
>
> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

Also, see here: [What's the fastest way to compare two objects in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866920/whats-the-fastest-way-to-compare-two-objects-in-php)